# Magento & ElasticSearch- Issue on SKU search

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I'm reading tons of Google search, but I cannot reach my goal.

I've a M1.9.x website with ES.

I've a custom module based on Smile Elastic Search (found on GitHub).

I need to search with PARTIAL sku.

I modified my mapping using the "copy_to" function to copy the value of SKU field on my multifield field.

I've a sku like 'ABC123' and i need to find it with "ABC12" query. How can I do this? Many thanks!